# Comparison of coefficient test across subsamples

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, lm

I am trying to conduct a comparison of coefficient tests across two subsamples. To achieve this, I do the following:

```
full_model <- lm(y ~ v1*subsample_dummy + fixed_effects, data=df)
reduced_model <- lm(y ~ v1 + subsample_dummy + fixed_effects, data=df)

test <- anova(full_model, reduced_model)
```

The above gives me the result.

However, I am not sure how to do the same in the situation where I have to **cluster** the models by, let's say, the `year` variable.

I can cluster the lm models using the following code:

```
library(sandwich)
# cluster by year
clustered_se <- vcovCL(full_model, ~ year) 
clustered_se1 <- vcovCL(reduced_model, ~ year)

# generate summaries with clustered standard errors 
a <- coeftest(full_model, vcov. = clustered_se) 
b <- coeftest(reduced_model, vcov. = clustered_se1)
```

However, the issue remains, as I still cannot do:

```
anova(a, b)
```

How to achieve the comparison of coefficient test across subsamples when the model requires standard error clustering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sandwich::vcovCL` to get essentially the same standard errors like `lfe::felm`. Let's estimate some models.

```
> est1 <- lfe::felm(y ~ x1 + x2 | id + firm | 0 | firm, data=d)  ## id + firm FE, clustered by firm
> est2 <- lfe::felm(y ~ x1 | id + firm | 0 | firm, data=d)  ## same, restricted model
> est3 <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + as.factor(id) + as.factor(firm), data=d)  ## as est1 w/o clustering
> est4 <- lm(y ~ x1 + as.factor(id) + as.factor(firm), data=d)  ## as restricted est3
```

Comparing the standard errors of **est3** with **est1**,

```
> lmtest::coeftest(est3, vcov.=\(x) 
+                  sandwich::vcovCL(x, cluster=d$firm, type='HC0'))[1:3, ]
             Estimate Std. Error  t value      Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 3.7416642 0.10554929 35.44945 5.454680e-177
x1          1.0432612 0.02965723 35.17730 3.631800e-175
x2          0.4904104 0.03186679 15.38939  5.822822e-48
> coef(summary(est1))
    Estimate Cluster s.e.  t value     Pr(>|t|)
x1 1.0432612   0.02968696 35.14207 1.799173e-13
x2 0.4904104   0.03189874 15.37398 2.931632e-09
```

yields essentially the same.

Thus, and according to a post on *Cross validated* [[1]](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/132521/163114) we could compare models **est1** and **est2** using an `lmtest::waldtest` (there's also a `lfe::waldtest` which works differently).

```
> lmtest::waldtest(est3, est4, vcov=\(x) 
+                  sandwich::vcovCL(x, cluster=d$firm, type='HC0'))
Wald test

Model 1: y ~ x1 + x2 + as.factor(id) + as.factor(firm)
Model 2: y ~ x1 + as.factor(id) + as.factor(firm)
  Res.Df Df      F    Pr(>F)    
1    966                        
2    967 -1 236.83 < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

Hope this brings you a step further.

BTW: You definitely could file a **feature request** on this as an issue on the author's [GitHub](https://github.com/MatthieuStigler/lfe/issues).

---

*Data:*

```
> set.seed(42)
> n <- 1e3
> d <- data.frame(x1=rnorm(n), x2=rnorm(n), id=factor(sample(20, n, replace=TRUE)),
+                 firm=factor(sample(13, n, replace=TRUE)), u=rnorm(n))
> id.eff <- rnorm(nlevels(d$id))
> firm.eff <- rnorm(nlevels(d$firm))
> d$y <- d$x1 + 0.5 * d$x2 + id.eff[d$id] + firm.eff[d$firm] + d$u
```